# How to iterate an reorder over 200 lines of strings in Python 3+

Tags: string, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a file with 278 rows of application id combinations that look like this:

```
Windows Azure Active Directory                               00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000
Microsoft.SMIT                                               8fca0a66-c008-4564-a876-ab3ae0fd5cff
```

I wrote a bit of Python regex:

```
lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        newline = re.sub('\s+', ' ', line)
        print(newline)
```

Now I have them looking like this:

```
Windows Azure Active Directory 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 
Microsoft.SMIT3 8fca0a66-c008-4564-a876-ab3ae0fd5cff 
Microsoft Azure Workflow 00000005-0000-0000-c000-000000000000
```

Initially I thought I could do:

```
newnewline = re.sub('\s\d', '\": \"', newline)
```

But it was removing the \s\d (space and digit), but since the app names have spaces I wasn't sure what else I could use for a regex to match.

Example (first one missing the initial 0):

```
Windows Azure Active Directory":  "0000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000
Windows Azure Active Directory": "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000
```

So I am still stuck here.

I need/want to turn all 278 of them into a Python dictionary like this.

```
"00000004-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000": "Microsoft.Lync",
"00000006-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000": "Microsoft.Office365Portal",
```

Comment: You used regex you said, show us that code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you are doing is removing some internal whitespace and creating a dictionary where the last element in a line is the key for the rest of the line. Using regular expressions is overkill. If `lines` is the list of lines with which you start the question, the following assembles the dictionary you want without needing to use regular expressions:

```
d = {}
for line in lines:
    data = line.split()
    d[data[-1]] = ' '.join(data[:-1])
```

Comment: Wow.  Yes. I was over thinking this.  Much appreciated.  Marked as the right answer.